# Прочитать fb2 в java (андроид устройства)

Tags: java, fb2

Хотел сделать Ридер книжек с форматом fb2 на планшет с четвёртым андроидом, и упёрся в проблему: а как прочитать этот формат? Можете подсказать код для чтения этого формата?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Достаточно прочитать первую строчку статьи в википеди про fb2 чтобы понять, что это просто XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте библиотеку [Fb2 parser](https://github.com/KursX/fb2parser).
Файл библиотеки `Fb2Parser.jar` закинуть в `libs` проекта и добавить зависимость

```
dependencies {
    compile files('src/main/libs/fb2parser.jar')
}
```

Comment: спасибо  вам за ответ!